# hls.js prevent rewind and keeping segments

Tags: javascript, html, http-live-streaming

HLS.js is keeping about 5 or so mins of video in the player to be able to rewind. This is causing an issue with memory on my app. Is there an option or a way to just play live and not have any ability or keeping of segments so that the memory isn't rising?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is being fixed. https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/pull/1845

Next release should have it. 0.11.1